# Emacs with smaller font size -> Text doesn't align

Tags: emacs, fonts

I have a problem with Emacs (which is a great editor by the way), when I change the default font size and font, my text doesn't align anymore.

In use it in vhdl-mode, and it is really annoying, that the text doesn't align. In other editor the text-alignment is fine, even though I have modified it in emacs.

Anyone their have a solution to this problem, rather going back to default font and default font-size?

Comment: What fonts are you changing between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you changed your font, were you careful to change it to a fixed width font? When you say it looks fine in another editor, is that editor using the same font?

You need to make sure that you use a fixed width (monospace) font in emacs or any other text editor to get text to line up properly. My guess is you picked a proportional font in emacs and you have a fixed width font in the other editor.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had choosen the Veranda font.

But it's their nicer alternative? I would really like a rounder fontset. I use emacs under Windows OS.

Comment: @Soren M: on windows I like consolas, it's the only font there where the l doesn't look like a 1. (That I know of, of coarse.) And I'm pretty sure that it comes pre-installed with windows XPsp2+. But I might just always install it first thing :-)

Comment: @quodlibetor: one thing I've noticed with Consolas is that it seems to essentially require ClearType, so it won't work too well on a CRT...